# Центрирование изображения в блоке меньшего размера.

Tags: jquery, вёрстка, javascript

Имеется div заданной высоты, ширина у div в процентах. В div вставлено изображение. При разрешении экрана более 1024 изображение центрируется. При разрешении равном или менее 1024 оно обрезается с одного края, т.к. ширина блока становится меньше ширины изображения. Как можно в таком случае горизонтально центрировать изображение средствами js и обрезать его с обоих боков?

Вариант с изменением размеров изображения не подходит, т.к. по высоте div фиксирован и изображение должно занимать его полностью.

HTML:

```
<div class="box">
    <img src="http://hashcode.ru/upfiles/logo.png">
</div>
<div class="box">
    <img src="http://hashcode.ru/upfiles/logo.png">
</div>
<div class="box">
    <img src="http://hashcode.ru/upfiles/logo.png">
</div>
<div class="box">
    <img src="http://hashcode.ru/upfiles/logo.png">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.box {
    width: 21%; 
    height: 70px; 
    background: #222;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 20px 2%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: @x01x, а не лучше ли просто масштабировать изображение, чем резать?

Comment: т.к. меняется только ширина блока при масштабировании будут отступы с верху и/или с низу. что не совсем подходит. интересует вариант именно обрезания по бокам.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[[@x01x](/users/18988/x01x)](/users/18988/x01x), на моё предложение в комментарии, вы не отреагировали. Значит, могу предложить [такой вариант решения](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/r6GBS/1/) вашей задачи. Только учтите, что решение [не очень кроссбраузерное](http://caniuse.com/#search=transform).

```
.box {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 21%; 
    height: 70px;
    margin: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid #999;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.box img{
    position: absolute;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
    -moz-transform: translateX(-50%);
    -ms-transform: translateX(-50%);
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

---

**UPD** [Вариант с JS](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/r6GBS/2/)

```
var box = $('.box'),
    img = $('img', box),
    imgW = img.width();
$(window).resize(function(){
    img.css({
        marginLeft: (box.width() - imgW) / 2
    });
}).resize();
```

Comment: спасибо за вариант решения. если не найду решения через js, то воспользуюсь.

Comment: @x01x, странно... Обычно, сначала ищут решения без JS, но если вам желателен именно такой вариант, то можно соорудить. Дополнил в ответе.

Comment: спасибо. то что нужно!